# Glassfish Web Service Monitoring

Tags: web-services, glassfish, tcpmon

I'm trying to monitor the request/response envelopes for a web service that I've developed in java and deployed on Glassfish.  I have a trivial example java client that is using bindings generated from the wsdl by wsimport.

I've tried various tool/utilities to monitor the exchange (WireShark, TCPMon and TCPMonitor for Eclipse) but each shows exactly the same thing...a call to glassfish to retrieve the wsdl, and that is all!   I know that my request is getting through, because the database is being updated.   However, I cannot see the actual request/response envelopes that cause this.

I feel like I'm missing something fundamental here.  Does the request/response use a different port?  The wsdl says the service is on 8080 which is the same port that I'm monitoring.

Any ideas?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, the sole difference is that the WS was deployed in jboss_4.2.3. I managed to crack the problem using wireshark. More information on the solution you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14850672/capture-soap-requests-responses-on-specific-host-windows-server/14891518#14891518).

Regarding the rest of your questions:

- typically the call comes on 8080 but the response returns on a different port (every time another one).

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

- Specify only IP address in Wireshark filter, without port and you should see all traffic
- Add this portion of code in your client, it will catch SOAP envelope:

Code:

```
SOAPMessage msg = ((SOAPMessageContext) context).getMessage ();
SOAPPart sp = msg.getSOAPPart ();
SOAPEnvelope env = sp.getEnvelope ();
```